How to say "Each one of the following" in German?
I am trying to formulate the following sentence in German:

I need to write a sentence with each of these verbs: geben, zeigen,
bringen, kochen.

To clarify, I want to clearly convey that it needs to be 4 sentences, one with each verb, not one sentence with all 4 verbs.
My attempt was

Ich muss einen Satz schreiben, mit jedem Verb von diesen Verben:
geben, zeigen, bringen, kochen.

I asked chat GPT and it suggested this

Ich muss für jedes dieser Verben einen eigenen Satz schreiben: geben,
zeigen, bringen, kochen.

Which I don't really understand the grammar construct used here.
How would you formulate this sentence?
What is the general way to say "each of" when giving a list of options?

The root problem here seems to be that the English version is unclear, perhaps ambiguous. (It seems you noticed that yourself since you added a "To clarify, ..." sentence to the question.) I'd suggest rephrasing to make it very explicit what you're trying so say. One thing that was confusing to me is that you said "a sentence" when you meant "four sentences". An automated translator will never stop and say "Wait, I don't understand what you mean." They just go ahead and use what they think is the most probable meaning.

The Chatgpt translation is clear - contrary to the English original: it back-translates to: I have to write a separate sentence for each of the following verbs.

"Which I don't really understand the grammar construct used here." what of that don't you understand? There is really no specific grammar construct used here.


I need to write a sentence with each of these verbs: geben, zeigen, bringen, kochen.

You may translate this very literally by replacing each of these with jedem dieser or jedem von diesen:

Ich muss einen Satz mit jedem dieser Verben schreiben: …
Ich muss einen Satz mit jedem von diesen Verben schreiben: …

However, that means it has to be one sentence having all of those verbs. At once. This is because jeder/jede/jedes covers both each and all in German and there is no pronoun that distinguishes both selections. In fact, you could write

Ich muss einen Satz mit allen diesen Verben schreiben: …

and the meaning would be exactly the same.
So how to tell this apart in German? — By changing the number of results.

Ich muss Sätze mit jedem dieser Verben schreiben: …
Ich muss Sätze mit jedem von diesen Verben schreiben: …
Ich muss Sätze mit allen diesen Verben schreiben: …

This is at least ambiguous though most German speakers will understand that there's one sentence for each verb. And not multiple sentences with each one having all the verbs.
If you want to tell this unambiguosly, write

Ich muss Sätze mit jeweils einem dieser Verben schreiben: …
Ich muss Sätze mit jeweils einem von diesen Verben schreiben: …

What ChatGPT suggests is another way to make in unambiguous. Let me reorder its proposal and reword it:

Ich muss einen eigenen Satz mit jedem von diesen Verben schreiben: …

See how this matches your own idea? And yes,

Ich muss eigene Sätze mit allen diesen Verben schreiben: …

is also unambiguously each.

The mathematically inclined aspect of my mind wants to point out that for "Ich muss Sätze mit jeweils einem dieser Verben schreiben" one could always take the same word from the list... perhaps "... mit jeweils einem anderen dieser Verben ..." would be truly unambiguous?

You can use je to make it clear:

Ich muss je einen Satz mit den folgenden Verben schreiben: geben, zeigen, bringen, kochen.



Ich muss für jedes dieser Verben einen eigenen Satz schreiben: geben, zeigen, bringen, kochen.

Is the way I would formulate this sentence, too.
You probably have a hard time to identify the grammatical structure of dieser Verben. This is a noun phrase in the genitive case. More specifically, it is a genitivus partitivus, a genitive marking that something is a part of something else.
Translating the genitive into English is hard in this examples, because English does not really use genitive on plural nouns. Even with a singular noun, the genitivus partitivus is not really idiomatic:

Alle Stücke dieses Kuchens


*All this cake's slices
All slices of this cake

